# Regex result capturing in c#

Tags: c#, regex, capture

Hi can someone help me with regexp to capture everything between the double quotes in the text below using c#.

```
$pageProcessId = "abc_def_ghi";
```

also the string can be

```
$pageProcessId="abc_def_ghi";
```

trying to capture abc_def_ghi basically...hope it makes sense.

thank you very much.

Comment: Your always explaining your questions using PHP while asking something C# related? And capturing everything between the double quotes is done by just making a string right? :s This question doesn't make sence to me.

Comment: Hi there, well i am parsing a php file using c# and i am trying to capture everything within double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

`\"(?<InsideString>.*?)\"`

*InsideString* is just a capture group name, you can delete it and just keep this.

```
\".*?\"
```

Comment: hi thanks for looking at it for me....can you please re-write it considering this as a whole string " $pageProcessId = "abc_def_ghi"; " hope this is clear.....i am actually parsing a php file and trying to match anything starting with $pageProcessId =  and then get anything within the quotes.

Comment: Hi, sure it's simple, you just have to do it like this : \$pageProcessId\s*=\s*\".*?\"